# Boundary-shifting wordplay (or mishearing) in Chinese?

Tags: word-choice, syntax

In English, ambiguity (mishearing, or intentional wordplay) can be created by
boundary shifting.  Do you have anything like this in Chinese?  Thank you.  HH

(written space -shifting)

```
notable -- no table -- not able

AMIABLE TOGETHER = AM I ABLE TO GET HER? (by Dmitri Borgmann)
              is a perfect longer example.
```

(aural (spoken?) "juncture" -shifting) -- (moving of perceptual grouping?)

```
grade A    ---   gray day 
night-rate   ---  nitrate 
I scream     ---   ice cream 
a nice man   ---   an ice man 
home-acre    ---   hoe-maker
```

Intended tags:  Wordplay, Speech-error, Humor

Comment: Something interesting to read: http://www.matrix67.com/blog/archives/2571

Comment: This is my thread (my question) so I can comment, but to comment on other threads, I apparently need 50 reputation points ! --  ( All these rules ! -- and this rule makes zero sense.) After I get to 50 points I will feel more comfortable about this site. (Currently I feel deprived, handcuffed.) ______________________________________ Thank you for the 3 answers so far.  They are all excellent.  HH

Comment: Excuse me while I kiss the sky

Answer (score 7):

> 喜欢上 一个人

`to get to like someone` or `to get to like being alone`

> 喜欢 上一个 人

`to like the previous man/woman`

> 喜欢 上 一个人

`to like to f-word someone`

Answer (score 5):

Chinese do have mishearing issue, because of the limited pronunciation and tones.

The classic example may be all foreigners know when they were starting to learn Chinese tones is:

> 请问shui jiao 多少钱一 wan ？

If foreigners don't pay attention to the tones, It could be: *请问水饺多少钱一碗？(How much for one bow of dumplings, please?)*, or *请问睡觉多少钱一晚？(How much for sleeping with you for one night, please?)*. 睡觉 and 水饺 have same pronunciation but different tones, 晚 and 碗 have the exactly same pronunciation and tone.

Comment: Mandarin only has 4 sounds, in contrast, Cantonese has 9 sounds, mishearing problem is less common.

Comment: I don't think mishearing is common issue in any language, but Chinese do have.

Answer (score 4):

There are wordplay in every language, Chinese is no exception.

Example:

"下雨天留客，天留人不留。"
"Raining day make the guest stay, although heaven keeps the guest, the host does not."

"下雨天，留客天。留人不?" "留！"
"Raining day, a day to keep the guest.  Do you keep the guest ?" 
(answer) "Keep!"

Example:

From Steven Chow's movies-

西人，狠樣 ( can't explain here because these are vulgar terms)

Comment: *西人，狠樣 ( can't explain here because these are vulgar terms)* --( it is in Cantonese)

Answer (score 1):

Another example, "小處不可隨便" is a motto which means one should be serious even on small matters.